# How to fix "no module name mysql"error when connecting python file to mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

```
import mysql.connector


cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
    user='db',
    password='yab@db',
    host='3306',
    database='database1'
)


cursor = cnx.cursor()


query = 'SELECT * FROM your_table'
cursor.execute(query)


results = cursor.fetchall()


for row in results:
    print(row)


cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

I am try to connect to mysql database through python but it showed error no module named mysql connector even though i install python_mysql_connector during the installation of mysql

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to install the package `mysql-connector-python` because that's where the `mysql.connector` Class comes from. Also if you're using a virtual environment, you should try to install it within that rather than doing it globally.

> pip install mysql-connector-python

Comment: If you still have issues, be careful to install it on the right user if virtual environment are set or you are not sudo.

Answer (score 1):

First do `pip install mysql-connector-python`.

Now pass your data accordingly into the `mydb` method and try the code below:

```py
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="",
  database="mysql"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM db")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
  print(x)
```

I tested it, it works fine for me.

If you still experience issues with this, it must be that something is wrong with your database connection or that python in your script doesn't correspond to the right path. If that is the case, do this:
`<full path to python> -m pip install mysql-connector-python` and try again.